# Native heap android OOM hardware acceleration

Tags: java, android, memory, out-of-memory, hardware-acceleration

first off I'm using a Nexus 7 (the 2013 one with the 1080p screen) running android 4.4(kitkat) and using eclipse with the adb pluggin for windows(64bit I think). My apps minSdkVersion is set to 11 and only operates in the landscape orientation.

The problem is I keep getting a OOM error after leaving my app run for a while. My dalvik heap remains constant at around 25~MB but using Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() and Debug.getNativeHeapSize() it says my native heap size is constantly increasing until the app crashes from a OOM error.

I'm using hardware acceleration by declaring android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in my manifest and using setLayerType( View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE , null ) in my SurfaceView constructor to set it to be hardware accelerated.

(Using setLayerType( View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE , null ) was my problem, I removed it and the memory leak stopped).

Weird thing is once I press the home button then go back to my app the native heap resets back to its initial value.

My proof the dalvik heap is remaining constant and the native heap is growing is from these messages in LogCat:

debug.native heap   : allocated 191.45MB of 191.73MB (0.28MB free)
debug.VM heap memory: allocated 23.00MB VM Heap Size: 31.00MB  MaxHeapSize: 192.00MB
:  availMemory 634.95MB , lowMemory? false , threshold 96.00MB
: canvas.isHardwareAccelerated() = true
: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4566K, 30% free 22608K/32236K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
: debug. =================================
: debug.native heap   : allocated 197.01MB of 197.27MB (0.26MB free)
: debug.VM heap memory: allocated 22.00MB VM Heap Size: 31.00MB  MaxHeapSize: 192.00MB
:  availMemory 629.38MB , lowMemory? false , threshold 96.00MB

Then once the native heap is full i get the error:

```
01-03 17:18:23.424: A/libc(15604): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 15604 (ebe.kingscastle)
01-03 17:18:23.524: I/DEBUG(176): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-03 17:18:23.524: I/DEBUG(176): Build fingerprint: 'google/razor/flo:4.4.2/KOT49H/937116:user/release-keys'
01-03 17:18:23.524: I/DEBUG(176): Revision: '0'
01-03 17:18:23.524: I/DEBUG(176): pid: 15604, tid: 15604, name: ebe.kingscastle  >>> com.kaebe.kingscastle <<<
01-03 17:18:23.524: I/DEBUG(176): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     r0 00000000  r1 00020004  r2 00000000  r3 795402d8
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     r4 795402d8  r5 000000a0  r6 bef63450  r7 75aac91c
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     r8 791e0378  r9 00000000  sl 00000001  fp 76b8ef38
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     ip 00000001  sp bef63378  lr 400e7e6b  pc 4015ab6a  cpsr 60010030
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     d0  44ece00043de0000  d1  00000000441b8000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     d2  43de000000000000  d3  44bda00043ce0000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     d4  44bda00044b9a000  d5  43ac800043ce0000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     d6  43ce000043cc8000  d7  44b9a00044bda000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     d8  0000078000000450  d9  41600000440a0000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     d10 0000000042080000  d11 0000000000000000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     d16 0000000000000000  d17 3ff0000000000000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     d18 0000000000000000  d19 3ff0000000000000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     d26 3ff0000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     d28 3ff0000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
01-03 17:18:23.614: I/DEBUG(176):     scr 20000012
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176): backtrace:
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #00  pc 0000bb6a  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::LinearAllocator::newPage(unsigned int)+27)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #01  pc 0000bba3  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::LinearAllocator::ensureNext(unsigned int)+52)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #02  pc 0000bbe7  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::LinearAllocator::alloc(unsigned int)+40)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #03  pc 00013e95  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #04  pc 00014621  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #05  pc 00012ccd  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #06  pc 000136a3  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #07  pc 00013719  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #08  pc 0001a179  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #09  pc 00022717  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #10  pc 0002275f  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #11  pc 000231fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #12  pc 00065cf3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #13  pc 0001dbcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #14  pc 0004e123  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #15  pc 00026fe0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #16  pc 0002dfa0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #17  pc 0002b638  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #18  pc 00060865  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInvokeMethod(Object*, Method const*, ArrayObject*, ArrayObject*, ClassObject*, bool)+392)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #19  pc 000687c7  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #20  pc 00026fe0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #21  pc 0002dfa0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #22  pc 0002b638  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #23  pc 00060581  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #24  pc 00049d0b  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #25  pc 0004cde7  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #26  pc 0004db0b  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+354)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #27  pc 0000105b  /system/bin/app_process
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #28  pc 0000e34b  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+50)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #29  pc 00000d7c  /system/bin/app_process
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176): stack:
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef63338  00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef6333c  400e7e6b  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc+4254)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef63340  00020004  
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef63344  40120e00  /system/lib/libc.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef63348  400e6dcd  /system/lib/libc.so (dlmalloc)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef6334c  795402d8  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef63350  000000a0  
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef63354  bef63450  [stack]
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef63358  75aac91c  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef6335c  791e0378  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef63360  00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef63364  00000001  
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef63368  76b8ef38  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef6336c  400e4bf9  /system/lib/libc.so (malloc+12)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef63370  795402d8  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef63374  4015ab69  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::LinearAllocator::newPage(unsigned int)+26)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #00  bef63378  7dbdc008  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef6337c  4015aba7  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::LinearAllocator::ensureNext(unsigned int)+56)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #01  bef63380  795402d8  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef63384  4015abeb  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::LinearAllocator::alloc(unsigned int)+44)
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):     #02  bef63388  00000001  
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef6338c  79540150  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef63390  40bdbf45  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-03 17:18:23.624: I/DEBUG(176):          bef63394  40bd9e99  /system/lib/libhwui.so
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176): memory near r1:
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     0001ffe4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     0001fff4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     00020004 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     00020014 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     00020024 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     00020034 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     00020044 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     00020054 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     00020064 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     00020074 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     00020084 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     00020094 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     000200a4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     000200b4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     000200c4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     000200d4 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176): memory near r3:
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     795402b8 0000000c 0a0a0a01 00000008 3f400000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     795402c8 00000000 00000000 0000000b 7953e5f8  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     795402d8 00020000 00000400 7dbfbfec 7dbdc008  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     795402e8 79540400 3f986f40 0005fae0 00001fd0  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     795402f8 00000000 0000004b 00000001 000000c5  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540308 000001a5 00000046 000000d1 3e450000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540318 3ed28000 3e858000 3f1d8000 0000004b  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540328 00610000 00000000 0000000f ffffff20  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540338 00000000 00000000 76b97ef0 0000005b  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540348 76448690 42923333 3f800000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540358 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540368 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540378 00000000 ff888888 00000000 40800000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540388 0b000501 752e3d30 00000001 00000001  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540398 00000054 00000023 0000000a 00000001  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     795403a8 4c2d6e65 2d6e7461 75005355 78eba550  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176): memory near r4:
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     795402b8 0000000c 0a0a0a01 00000008 3f400000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     795402c8 00000000 00000000 0000000b 7953e5f8  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     795402d8 00020000 00000400 7dbfbfec 7dbdc008  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     795402e8 79540400 3f986f40 0005fae0 00001fd0  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     795402f8 00000000 0000004b 00000001 000000c5  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540308 000001a5 00000046 000000d1 3e450000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540318 3ed28000 3e858000 3f1d8000 0000004b  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540328 00610000 00000000 0000000f ffffff20  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540338 00000000 00000000 76b97ef0 0000005b  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540348 76448690 42923333 3f800000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540358 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540368 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540378 00000000 ff888888 00000000 40800000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540388 0b000501 752e3d30 00000001 00000001  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     79540398 00000054 00000023 0000000a 00000001  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     795403a8 4c2d6e65 2d6e7461 75005355 78eba550  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176): memory near r6:
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63430 00000000 79540150 7644dd28 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63440 6d46ea14 41504418 bef6351c 40bd971d  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63450 bef6346c 00000000 00000000 40be017d  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63460 448a0000 00000000 44f00000 79540150  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63470 791e0378 00000001 00000000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63480 440a0000 41600000 400d1028 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63490 791d0f28 7644dd28 00000000 40be871b  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef634a0 7644dd28 00000000 00000001 791d0f28  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef634b0 bef63508 40be8763 00410001 7644dd28  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef634c0 00000000 00000004 6d46ea2c 40be9201  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef634d0 448a0000 00000001 00000000 40be91cd  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef634e0 41504408 40203cf5 448a0000 00000001  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef634f0 6d4e68b8 41522bd0 00000000 00000780  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63500 00000450 00000001 6d46ea14 00000001  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63510 00000008 415e6fd0 41ed3c88 41553127  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63520 6d46ea14 6f0b0a82 40203caf 41504418  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176): memory near r7:
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     75aac8fc 75cef668 fefefe00 00000000 43cc8001  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     75aac90c 00000000 3f800000 00000000 3f800000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     75aac91c 40bf9b88 752d6fc8 fbfbfb00 44b9a000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     75aac92c 43ca0000 44bda000 43cc0000 40bf9740  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     75aac93c 752cc218 00000000 44bf2000 43cc8000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     75aac94c 44c2a000 43e00000 752c45b8 75cef668  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     75aac95c 40bf9700 00000000 43cc8001 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     75aac96c 3f800000 00000000 3f800000 40bf9740  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     75aac97c 78e9b7a8 00000000 44bee000 43ce0000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     75aac98c 44c2e000 43de0000 76b95460 75cef668  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     75aac99c 40bf9b00 00000000 43cc8001 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     75aac9ac 3f800000 00000000 3f800000 40bf9b88  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     75aac9bc 752d6fc8 43cd0000 44bee000 43ca0000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     75aac9cc 44c2e000 43cc0000 40bf9740 752cc218  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     75aac9dc 75aac900 44c46000 43cc8000 44c7e000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     75aac9ec 43e00000 752c45b8 75cef668 40bf9700  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176): memory near r8:
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     791e0358 00000001 00000002 00000003 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     791e0368 00000000 000003e8 00000000 00000243  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     791e0378 40bfa170 00000780 00000450 3a888889  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     791e0388 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     791e0398 baed7304 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     791e03a8 00000000 bf800000 00000000 bf800000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     791e03b8 3f800000 80000000 3f800000 00000013  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     791e03c8 3f800000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     791e03d8 00000000 3f800000 00000000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     791e03e8 00000000 00000000 3f800000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     791e03f8 00000000 00000000 00000000 3f800000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     791e0408 00000010 00000002 7644c788 752c3078  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     791e0418 00000000 00000000 44f00000 448a0000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     791e0428 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     791e0438 00000000 3f800000 00000000 3f800000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     791e0448 00000000 00000000 3f800000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176): memory near fp:
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     76b8ef18 00250003 00550043 004e0056 00030047  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     76b8ef28 00000000 00000007 00000040 0000001b  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     76b8ef38 76b97af8 76b97c78 76b97c70 76b97c88  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     76b8ef48 00000018 0000005b 76448690 44160000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     76b8ef58 3f800000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     76b8ef68 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     76b8ef78 00000000 00000000 00000000 ff888888  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     76b8ef88 00000000 40800000 0b010501 791e06e0  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     76b8ef98 00000001 00000001 00000009 0000005b  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     76b8efa8 76448690 42923333 3f800000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     76b8efb8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     76b8efc8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     76b8efd8 00000000 ff444444 00000000 40800000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     76b8efe8 0b000501 78ebaf68 00000001 00000001  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     76b8eff8 00000054 0000002b 00000001 00000010  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     76b8f008 00000000 00000000 76e80480 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176): memory near sp:
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63358 75aac91c 791e0378 00000000 00000001  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63368 76b8ef38 400e4bf9 795402d8 4015ab69  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63378 7dbdc008 4015aba7 795402d8 4015abeb  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63388 00000001 79540150 40bdbf45 40bd9e99  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63398 79540150 40bda625 00000003 00000001  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef633a8 752c3280 448a1000 448a0000 448a0000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef633b8 00000000 00000001 76b95460 448a0000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef633c8 00000000 00000450 00000780 bef63450  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef633d8 40bdbf45 bef63450 00000001 0000010d  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef633e8 00000000 00000001 76b8ef38 40bd8ccf  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef633f8 00000001 75aac91c 00000001 7953c9e0  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63408 791e0378 40bd96a7 448a0000 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63418 00000000 400e4c0d 00000000 75aac91c  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63428 00000000 791d0f28 00000000 79540150  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63438 7644dd28 00000000 6d46ea14 41504418  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     bef63448 bef6351c 40bd971d bef6346c 00000000  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176): code around pc:
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     4015ab48 6182020c b508bd10 695a4603 f0213107  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     4015ab58 18110003 615969da 61d91c51 ebf0f7fe  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     4015ab68 60022200 b510bd08 f7ff4604 bb08ffc0  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     4015ab78 b16b68e3 f5b06820 d2093f00 f5b10041  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     4015ab88 bf283f00 3100f44f f0221cca 60230303  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     4015ab98 682169a0 46201842 f7ff61a2 68e1ffd4  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     4015aba8 6008b101 60e06923 6120b903 f0203007  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     4015abb8 60a20203 b538bd10 68433103 0503f021  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     4015abc8 429d4604 4629d909 ff91f7ff e00fb928  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     4015abd8 300760e0 0003f020 4620bd38 f7ff4629  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     4015abe8 68a0ffc2 194269a1 1b4d60a2 bd3861a5  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     4015abf8 46204629 ffa7f7ff 6a236921 62221c5a  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     4015ac08 68e36001 2b006120 e7e1d1e3 edd0b570  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     4015ac18 f2407a05 ee1773cf 429a2a90 4604b086  
01-03 17:18:23.644: I/DEBUG(176):     4015ac28 461e460d 4b33d804 7ae7eef8 e00b447b  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     4015ac38 4282482e 4b30d804 7acbeefa e003447b  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176): code around lr:
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     400e7e48 e0043608 fafcf003 210c2600 49356001  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     400e7e58 f8d14479 079321bc f501d53f f7fd70e0  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     400e7e68 e03aed3c 42b06898 a8d4f43f b8d5f7ff  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     400e7e78 42b56895 aa31f43f ba32f7ff 447e4e2a  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     400e7e88 01bcf8d6 0204f040 21bcf8c6 36fff04f  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     400e7e98 4b13e462 d8d5429f f04fe467 e4850901  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     400e7ea8 f01268da f43f0f08 e4d1acc1 071068da  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     400e7eb8 ace4f57f 481de6cf f7ff4478 481cb8b1  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     400e7ec8 f7ff4478 688cb8ad f43f4294 e5c9adc8  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     400e7ed8 f47f1c71 2500ac22 4630e7d0 8ffee8bd  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     400e7ee8 7ffffffe 00032d8c 0003d6d6 0003d6ba  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     400e7ef8 0003d6a6 0003d63e 0003d5ae 0003d556  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     400e7f08 0003d53c 0003d51a 0003d4de 0003d474  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     400e7f18 00032ac0 0003d3dc 0003d384 0003d36c  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     400e7f28 0003d352 0003d324 0003d2f6 0003293c  
01-03 17:18:23.654: I/DEBUG(176):     400e7f38 00032934 4ff7e92d 4b5c461e 468a4604  
01-03 17:18:23.834: W/ActivityManager(593):   Force finishing activity com.kaebe.kingscastle/com.kaebe.kingscastlelib.KingsCastle
01-03 17:18:24.174: I/ActivityManager(593): Process com.kaebe.kingscastle (pid 15604) has died.
01-03 17:18:24.174: I/WindowState(593): WIN DEATH: Window{42329cd8 u0 SurfaceView}
01-03 17:18:24.174: I/WindowState(593): WIN DEATH: Window{42af0fe8 u0 com.kaebe.kingscastle/com.kaebe.kingscastle.KingsCastleFree}
01-03 17:18:24.184: I/WindowState(593): WIN DEATH: Window{4236fa28 u0 SurfaceView}
01-03 17:18:24.184: I/WindowState(593): WIN DEATH: Window{4236efa8 u0 com.kaebe.kingscastle/com.kaebe.kingscastlelib.KingsCastle}
01-03 17:18:24.194: I/ActivityManager(593): Start proc com.kaebe.kingscastle for activity com.kaebe.kingscastle/.KingsCastleFree: pid=17067 uid=10115 gids={50115}
01-03 17:18:24.204: D/dalvikvm(17067): Late-enabling CheckJNI
01-03 17:18:24.235: D/Zygote(178): Process 15604 terminated by signal (11)
```

I want to know how to prevent native heap memory leaks since i have no idea how to alloc on the native block over the dalvik heap.

I solved the issue by the way, just want to write it out to help other people since I couldn't find an answer to this from days of searching.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I spent days looking for a solution to why my native heap was increasing and my dalvik heap remained constant. After many questions and android documentation pages read i eventually tried to shut off hardware acceleration since I came across a OOM question relating the two already.

I removed the line setLayerType( View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE , null ) from my SurfaceView and the problem went away. I added that line after some advice from some suggestions on trying to get hardware acceleration turned on and i never really understood what i was doing there. For some reason that line caused about 1mb/2seconds to be added to the native heap until my program crashed.

So to anyone who's looking for solutions to problems try one thing at a time and understand what your trying before you copy paste it to your code.

I still don't know why that caused the native heap to constantly increase though.

I hope this helps someone with OOM native heap issues.

Comment: I have the same problem while user was playing video inside webview. If I  hardwareAccelerated="true" it crashes on kitkat but hardwareAccelerated="false" cause video not to play for most/all android os versions. Any idea for a solution?

Comment: I spend months trying to find the memory leak in my digital signage software, which is supposed to run 24/24 non stop. I ended initiating reboots when the memory got too low and I searched my code for weeks in order to find what I did wrong.

So I wanted to thank you for your answer, my leak problem is completely good and my application runs smooth as silk.

Answer (score 0):

when animation over 
try to add setLayerType( View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE , null) in order to turn off hardware acceleration
maybe solove the issue?